# Rewrite rule on application gateway azure

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

i would like to implement a rewrite rule on my Application Gateway v2 or other way if exist on Azure.

On application gateway i setup 2 path based rule for our main site that i call mywebsite.it deployed to webapp1:

1- if i reach mywebsite.it/function* it redirect traffic correctly to webapp2;

2- if i reach from mywebsite.it/myapplication*, for example mywebsite.it/myapplication/images/xyz the application start with mywebsite.it/function*. This rule point also to webapp2;

I would like to do this for scenario 2. From mywebsite.it/myapplication/images/xyz, apply a rewrite that change only /myapplication/, for example mywebsite.it/function/images/xyz. I need to mantain the path after function/* in rewrite operation(it is not static and change every time a user make a request when they pass from mywebsite.it/myapplication* )

I tried to configure the rewrite but it didn't work:

[image]

[image]

I can't try evaluate path map, becouse in our http setting applied to path base rules(is the same becouse web app is the same), override backend path is enabled with /. Without it application didn't work.

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Hi Emanuele ,Could you please refer this for [Rewrite URL with Azure Application Gateway - Azure portal | GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url.md#rewrite-http-headers-and-url-with-application-gateway)

Comment: Hi, i think that i tried that but it didn't work :( . We solved code side

Comment: My problem statement is that I have a webapp1.net and webapp2.net, my requirement that when user type webapp1.net than Azure application gateway redirect user to webapp2.net but the browser URL should be the same webapp1.net

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest you to please set the correct value for “Pattern to match” and “URL path value” and create the require object for HTTP header rewrite as it has stated according to the below Microsoft document. As it seems you have set wrong value for “Pattern to match” and “URL path value”.

Refer this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-portal

Comment: my problem statement is that I have a  https://webapp1.net and https://webapp2.net, my requirement that when user type https://webapp1.net than Azure application gateway redirect user to https://webapp2.net but the browser URL should be the same http://webapp1.net

Answer (score 1):

The pattern to match is a regular expression.  In regular expressions, the forward slash ("/") is a reserved character so it must be escaped with a backslash ("\"), so it should look like ("\/").  Use regex101.com to test your regular expression and ensure that you get a match when you expect it and no match when you do not expect it.